# How to reduce execution time for multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysql

Yo!

I have this code. Basically it should return a list of avaiable jobs based on the location and what position user looked for...

I am trying to figure out how to shorten the execution time for this...

```
$cities = $this->getChildren($location->city_id);

        foreach ($cities as $child) {
            $grandChildren = $this->getGrandChildren($child, false);

            foreach ($grandChildren as $grandChild) {
                $cities[] = $grandChild;
            }
        }

        $menu = $this->getPositionChildren($postion);
        $menu[] = $postion->menu_id;

        // var_dump($cities);

        foreach ($cities as $city) {
            $city_id = (!empty($city) ? "AND FIND_IN_SET('{$city}', town)" : '');
            foreach ($menu as $key) {
                $menu_id = (!empty($key) ? " AND FIND_IN_SET('{$key}', category_id)" : '');
                $queries[] = "SELECT ponuka_id as id FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "ponuky WHERE 1 {$city_id} {$menu_id} AND `published` = '1' ORDER BY `date` DESC";

                foreach ($queries as $query) {
                $result = mysql_query($query);

                if (!$result) {
                    return false;
                }

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                    if (!in_array($row->id, $this->_joblist, true)) {
                        $this->_joblist[] = $row->id;
                    }
                }
             }
        }
```

The code above can easily run over 1000 queries and as you can imagine, this takes time... Long time... any tips on how to improve this?

Comment: Remove your query from the loop!!

Comment: Avoid using FIND_IN_SET().... a better normalised database can be properly indexed, and the database can then use those indexes

Comment: Looks like you have to normalize your DB

Comment: And what is `WHERE 1 {$city_id} {$menu_id}` supposed to be?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava thanks! that actually helped tremendously...

Comment: @Kirito, I have faced the same problem many times, so I put every data of loop in an array or something like that & use it outside the loop in the query which reduces the time consumption tremendously. Good Luck.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava thanks! really helped!

Answer (score 0):

The code now looks like this and by taking the query out of the loop it runs a lot faster...

```
$cities = $this->getChildren($location->city_id);

        foreach ($cities as $child) {
            $grandChildren = $this->getGrandChildren($child, false);

            foreach ($grandChildren as $grandChild) {
                $cities[] = $grandChild;
            }
        }

        // $cities = $this->getCityInfoFromArray($cities);
        $menu = $this->getPositionChildren($postion);
        $menu[] = $postion->menu_id;

        var_dump($cities);

        foreach ($cities as $city) {
            $city_id = (!empty($city) ? "AND FIND_IN_SET('{$city}', town)" : '');
            foreach ($menu as $key) {
                $menu_id = (!empty($key) ? " AND FIND_IN_SET('{$key}', category_id)" : '');
                $queries[] = "SELECT ponuka_id as id FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "ponuky WHERE 1 {$city_id} {$menu_id} AND `published` = '1' ORDER BY `date` DESC";
            }
        }

        foreach ($queries as $query) {
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            if (!$result) {
                return false;
            }

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                if (!in_array($row->id, $this->_joblist, true)) {
                    $this->_joblist[] = $row->id;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your query is still inside loop. try to remove it completely if you want better performance & less CPU utilization.

Comment: I'm afraid this one is needed, since each query represents single job which is then put into joblist array... thanks anyway, you really helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this. Check if this works for you.

```
$city_id = ""; $city_id = "";
foreach ($cities as $city) {
            $city_id .= (!empty($city) ? " AND FIND_IN_SET('{$city}', town)" : '');
            foreach ($menu as $key) {
                $menu_id .= (!empty($key) ? " AND FIND_IN_SET('{$key}', category_id)" : '');
                                }
        }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT ponuka_id as id FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "ponuky WHERE 1 {$city_id} {$menu_id} AND `published` = '1' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
```